# ASP.NET error 404 page not found error page

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, http-status-code-404

i have ASP.NET web site and i am trying to make error page for runtime error and for 404 error (page not found).i have this code in web.config page.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error.aspx">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

when i am trying to enter some not existing page as http://localhost:63629/notexist.aspx i gets the 404.aspx page but when i enter http://localhost:63629/notexist (without .aspx) i gets the defaut error page from the browser.
how can i fix it?

Comment: Browser treats it as directory not page.

Comment: how can i add it to 404.aspx redirection?

Answer (score 0):

I think when you host your application to a server,.aspx is automatically added to any page URL

Comment: by mistake...it doesnt work. without .aspx i gets "The requested document was not found on this server."